# How do I take my random string and assign it to a variable?

Tags: python

So essentially I have this printing strings from my three lists...and I want to store what's produced into another list. I know how to store to other list but I can't figure a way to capture what is produced.

```
print(random.choice(a), random.choice(b), random.choice(c))
```

Is there a way to assign/record what is produced as a result of this statement?

Sorry if this is really easy or something...i'm just barely starting out.

Answer (score 0):

You can join them too. Change `' '` to what you want the delimiter to be.

```
string = ' '.join(random.choice(a), random.choice(b), random.choice(c))
```

Comment: I think you want a space in that empty string. Easier to use `.split()`.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac That may be the case, but doesn't that defeat the purpose of joining them into one string in the first place?

Comment: Ideally, it seems that the user would like to store this information for retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.format`:

```
In[3]: import random
In[4]: import string
In[5]: var = "{} {} {}".format(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase), random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase), random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase))
In[6]: print(var)
z j j
```